# I can't get window.innerHeight on IE7. How to fix?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, dom, internet-explorer-7

I can get `window.innerHeight` on Chrome.

1, How to get this property on IE7 via pure JS?

2, How to get this property on IE7 via jQuery?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Pure JS is difficult; so you'll need a script for that:

   http://andylangton.co.uk/articles/javascript/get-viewport-size-javascript/
2. jQuery on the other hand, is as simple as typing this:

   ```
   $(window).height();
   ```

[JS Fiddle link for a live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kAnTp/8/)

**Note:** The window size is *the size of the result section* in JS Fiddle.

## Update 1

I found a script that finds the scrollbar size from [JQuery Dimensions should have a method to return the scrollbar size](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-dimensions-should-have-a-method-to-return-the-scrollbar-size):

```
jQuery.getScrollBarSize = function() {
   var inner = $('<p></p>').css({
      'width':'100%',
      'height':'100%'
   });
   var outer = $('<div></div>').css({
      'position':'absolute',
      'width':'100px',
      'height':'100px',
      'top':'0',
      'left':'0',
      'visibility':'hidden',
      'overflow':'hidden'
   }).append(inner);

   $(document.body).append(outer);

   var w1 = inner.width(), h1 = inner.height();
   outer.css('overflow','scroll');
   var w2 = inner.width(), h2 = inner.height();
   if (w1 == w2 && outer[0].clientWidth) {
      w2 = outer[0].clientWidth;
   }
   if (h1 == h2 && outer[0].clientHeight) {
      h2 = outer[0].clientHeight;
   }

   outer.detach();

   return [(w1 - w2),(h1 - h2)];
};
```

The only problem left is it [always adds the scrollbar width & height to the dimensions](http://jsfiddle.net/gef7J/1/), regardless if there is a scrollbar or not. One solution to fix this problem is to detect when there is overflow in a web page, and at what dimension (vertical or horizontal).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But `window.innerHeight` will return the height with width of scroll bar if exists. And `$(window).height()` will return the height without width of scroll bar if exists.